# Routing issue between a switch and AP on different networks

Tags: routing

I have the following network below.  The router is a Juniper SRX 550 with 3 networks. 0/0/2 (currently disabled) is 172.16.64.1 /18, 0/0/3 is 172.16.128.1 /18, and 0/0/4 is 172.16.192.1 /18. The Juniper provides DHCP for these networks also, and this is working fine. Then I have 3 Netgear ProSAFE XS728T switches, 172.16.64.2 /18, 172.16.128.2 /18, and 172.16.192.2 /18. All 3 switches are on VLAN 1. I know to fix this, I can connect the AP to the 172.16.128.2 switch, but I HAVE to connect the AP to the 172.16.192.2 switch.

The problem is that, I have a Ubiquity WiFi AP on 172.16.128.3 /18, and it's connected to the 172.16.192.2 /18 switch. Because of this, I can't connect to it from the 172.16.128.0 or the 172.16.192.0 switches.  This looks like a routing issue.  How can I fix this?  I HAVE to connect the AP to this switch.

If I connect the WiFi AP to the 172.16.128.2 /18 switch, everything is fine.  I can connect to this WiFi from the 172.16.128.0 and the 172.16.192.0 devices, I have access to the Internet

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the device models and configurations.

Comment: The router is a Juniper SRX 550 with 3 networks.  0/0/2 (currently disabled) is 172.16.64.1 /18, 0/0/3 is 172.16.128.1 /18, and 0/0/4 is 172.16.192.1 /18.  The Juniper provides DHCP for these networks also, and this is working fine.  Then I have 3 Netgear ProSAFE XS728T switches, 172.16.64.2 /18, 172.16.128.2 /18, and 172.16.192.2 /18.  All 3 switches are on VLAN 1.  I know to fix this, I can connect the AP to the 172.16.128.2 switch, but I HAVE to connect the AP to the 172.16.192.2 switch.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the configurations. We may be able to help with con figuring a trunk.

Comment: That is not the configurations. I mean the actual configurations in the devices. You should sanitize by obfuscating the passwords and any public addresses, but we need to see the actual configurations.

Comment: I'll post my config.  The problem with trunk is that, when I tried it, it messed up my dhcp.  I called Netgear, and apparently, there's no way to stop the switches from giving out dhcp.  The router is the one handling dhcp.

Comment: DHCP can probably be handled.

Comment: Should be a way, but according to Netgear, no way.  If I can stop the switches from  giving out dhcp, then my issue is solved.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the switches do not have a DHCP server, so they are not giving out DHCP. You say you want the router to handle DHCP, and that is easy if you can have the correct VLAN trunked to the switch, then connect the WAP to a switch interface with the correct VLAN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The AP has to be on the same subnet as the switch (VLAN).  So you need to change the address of the AP to be in the 172.16.192.0/18 subnet.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with that is, when I connect my laptop to the AP, I'm getting a 172.16.192.0/ 18 IP.  I should be getting a 172.16.128.0 /18 IP.  The actual AP is on the 172.16.192.0 network, but I have  WiFi SSID in the 172.16.128.0 /18 network in the AP settings.

Comment: @Matt Damoz, you're going to have to reconfigure the SSID in the AP settings to use the 172.16.192.0 subnet.

Answer (score 0):

The interface on the switch (172.16.192.2/18) that is connecting switch to the router interface 0/0/4, needs to be configured as a trunk port. This trunk port needs to allow additional VLAN tagging. The number of additional VLAN depends on the number of WLAN your AP is configured for and the VLAN AP itself belongs to.